# Eevee is rendering my model inside out

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I have imported a model using xnaLara importer and when I try to render it in Eevee( viewport or F5) I can only see the inside of the the model.[image: Weird rendering]

If I switch to cycles it renders as I would expect it to, and it looks fine in solid draw mode. I have also tried different materials so I think it's a geometry problem. I have also checked that the normals are facing outside as well. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I have found a solution but I still can't explain what is actually going on( might be a bug in the model importer). When I import a model, it generates automatic materials. These materials work perfectly with cycles, but not with Eevee. Any changes made to the default material seem to produce the same z-fighting in the model. So I deleted the generated materials and manually remade them( with exactly the same node setup ) and BAM, no more glitchy renders.

I can only assume this is due to a bug in the generated material.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you zoom in ...

view >>>> clip start Reduce the size ....

[image: clip start]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a UV problem, try to Unwrap it again or just use texture coordinate node and use another method other than UV to see if it solves it...

Comment: I Tried using generated co-ordinates and then tried using a flat diffuse shader( no textures ), with the same results, so I don't think it's a UV issue.